# How to include 1x 1080p and 2x 4K video assets for tvOS

Tags: tvos, asset-catalog

I have an app that plays videos using `AVFoundation` APIs. These videos are currently placed into the project as separate files. They're 1080p videos, but now I have new 4K versions that I would like to use when the app is run on 4K Apple TVs, and it should continue using the 1080p assets on HD Apple TVs. I don't want both resolutions included in the app as that would dramatically increase the download size. App thinning does this for image assets placed in the asset catalog for 1x and 2x scales, but unfortunately it seems this isn't available for videos. Is there a way to provide 1x and 2x video assets such that the appropriate resolution is provided based on the Apple TV hardware downloading the app? Perhaps with on-demand resources? I do want the assets to always be available - the user shouldn't have to download them after the app is installed.

Comment: Any reason to not only ship with the 4K assets?

Comment: @DanielStorm Unfortunately the TV HD doesn't support playback of 4K videos. They still play, but with extremely poor choppy performance. https://support.apple.com/kb/SP724

Comment: Good point. AFAIK there's no naming conventions for local videos to have Xcode treat them the same way as asset catalogs. I take it hosting the content online, creating an HLS manifest, and then having the app play the HLS stream isn't an option?

Comment: Yah, I would strongly prefer they be included in the app download size as opposed to having to download them upon opening the app, or streaming them each time they're played.

Comment: Could consider zipping the video files and then unzipping them prior to playback. You’d have to unzip them each time playback occurs due to tvOS’s storage limits though, or hold a reference to the file after unzipping for the life of the application. Guess it depends on the trade offs in file size and processing time of unzipping prior to playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to feedback I submitted, I was informed this is possible if you use a Data Asset in Asset Catalog and the NSDataAsset API to retrieve the video. Tag the 4K version of the asset with the “APPLE 3” graphics feature class and put the 1080p version in the Any/Any slot. This will ensure the 4K version of the video asset is included for 4K Apple TV devices and the 1080p version is included for the others.